# How to load data in TabbedPage when a tab is clicked?

Tags: forms, xamarin, tabbedpage

I am using `TabbedPage` for navigation with tabs. All my `Page` classes have just an empty default constructor and I load my data in the `OnAppearing` method.  I have 5 tabs. As soon as I click on the second tab, the `OnAppearing` methods of the 3rd, 4th and 5th pages are also called.

How do I ensure that the data is only loaded when I click on the tab?

Comment: You have to react to OnCurrentPageChanged of the tabbed bar, ignoring it on startup when just adding new tabs. After that you can, for example, send messages to pages upon this event or call their code from your subclassed tabbed page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can get the index of currentPage in method `OnCurrentPageChanged` And if the index equals 1(second page) , use the `messagecenter` to send message to the page.Refer the following code .

> in Tabbed Page

```
protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
{
   base.OnCurrentPageChanged();

   int index = Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);

   if (index == 1)
   {
      MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, "click_second_tab");
   }

   else if (index == 2)
   {
      MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, "click_third_tab");
   }


}
```

> in the second page .Move the code that load data from onAppearing to the constructor

```
public MyPage1()
{

  //...
  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "click_second_tab", (obj) =>
  {
     //load your data here

      Console.WriteLine("11111");
  });

}
```

Comment: To clarify how this works: `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` code does not immediately load the data - what it does is save in MessagingCenter an action containing code starting with `//load your data here`. Later when corresponding `MessagingCenter.Send` happens, that action is executed, so the data is loaded.