# Xamarin forms: Adjacent tab get called when open a tab

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabs, tabbedpage

I am using `TabbedPage` for implementing tabs in my apps. I have 4 tabs and always open the second tab initially since the first tab is the home tab. When selecting the second tab third tab is also loading in the background and when selecting the third tab fourth tab is also loading in the background.

**TabbedPage Code:**

```
var homePage = new Pages.HomePage()
    {
        Title = "Home"
    };

    var secondPage= new SecondPage()
    {
        Title = "SecondPage"
    };

    var thirdPage = new ThirdPage()
    {
        Title = "ThirdPage"
    };

    var fourthPage = new FourthPage()
    {
        Title = "FourthPage"
    };

    Children.Add(homePage);
    Children.Add(secondPage);
    Children.Add(thirdPage);
    Children.Add(fourthPage);
    CurrentPage = Children[1];

  this.CurrentPageChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            var i = this.Children.IndexOf(this.CurrentPage);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                CallHomePage();
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                //SecondPage icon settings
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                //ThirdPage icon settings
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
               //FourthPage icon settings
            }
        };
```

**How can I stop the loading of the adjacent tab when selecting a tab?**

Comment: Here is a similar case that  you can refer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968876/how-to-load-data-in-tabbedpage-when-a-tab-is-clicked/53993902#53993902

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I will go through this and update you.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Please post it, it works...

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** You can get the index of currentPage in method OnCurrentPageChanged And if the index equals 1(second page) , use the messagecenter to send message to the page.Refer the following code .

> in Tabbed Page

```
protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
{
 base.OnCurrentPageChanged();

 int index = Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);

 if (index == 1)
 {
    MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, "click_second_tab");
 }

 else if (index == 2)
 {
  MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, "click_third_tab");
 }

 else if (index == 3)
 {
  //...
 }
}
```

> in the second page .Move the code that load data from onAppearing to the constructor

```
public SecondPage()
{

  //...
  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "click_second_tab", (obj) =>
  {
     //load your data here

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as with all arrays/lists in C#, the `Children` list is **zero-indexed**, which means the first element is at `Children[0]`.

Comment: I am loading 3 different lists in 3 tabs(the first tab is a home tab). When selecting the second tab third tab user dialogues are showing in UI, the same happens when selecting the third tab, showing the fourth tab user dialogues in the UI. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Edited the question with complete tabbed page code, can you please check?