# Xamarin forms TabbedPage CurrentPage does not call OnAppearing

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have 2 tabs into a `TabbedPage`. I am gonna label them `A` and `B`. When the user is on `B` I manually set `OnBackButtonPressed(){
  CurrentPage = A;
}`. That code swipe automatically to `A`.

The problem is if from `B` I swipe the screen to `A` then I swipe the screen to `B` the method `B.OnAppearing` will get called. But if from `B` I press the back button which set `CurrentPage = A;`, the tabbedPage swipe to `A` and then I swipe the screen to `B`, **the method `B.OnAppearing` does not get called**.

What should I do after setting `CurrentPage = A;`?

** Edited **

Here are the steps to test:

Swipe right:

[image]

You can see it get called:

[image]
[image]

Press back button:

[image]

Then swipe right:

[image]

You can see there is no new print:

[image]

Comment: I wrote a sample project and the B.OnAppearing did called. I uploaded my sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Tabbar-test) and you can check it. You can see the print messages in the console. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Thank you for taking the time to create a sample project. I tested your code and the result is the same as mine. Please take a look at the images I added on how to test it.

Comment: Yes, the onAppearing method does not been call after setting currentPage. I will do more research and update you if I find something. I would give you a workaround that you can use OnCurrentPageChanged to update data in each Content as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968876/how-to-load-data-in-tabbedpage-when-a-tab-is-clicked).

Comment: Opened a github issue here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10769, quote: The Android ViewPager, which is backing the TabbedPage, keeps a minimum number of pages loaded in memory to keep the UI fast and responsive. OnDisappearing does not get called until the pages are triggered to be removed from memory. It's an odd quirk, but this is expected behavior.