# Xamarin Forms Tabbed Page Tabs Initializing

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage, initializecomponent

I am developing a tabbed Page in Xamarin that consist of 3 tabs ( Tab1= "Home" , Tab2= "Chat" ,Tab3="Menu" )

When the App starts ( `MainPage = new TabbedPage()` ) it initializes (`InitializeComponent();`) all the tabs together at first.

My question is that if there is a way to initialize each component alone whenever the tab is pressed?

Comment: Are you trying to speed up app load, by delaying those InitializeComponent calls? Can you change what the XAML sees, to be quick at first? Sometimes it isn't the XAML itself (InitializeComponent), but the data that is being referenced. If its the data, see [How to load data in TabbedPage when a tab is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968876/how-to-load-data-in-tabbedpage-when-a-tab-is-clicked). For example, if a page has a `ListView` or `CollectionView`, you start with an *empty* items source (zero items). When page is clicked, add the items to the items source.

Comment: In any case, please **show your code**. And state what **problem you are trying to solve**. Isolate the problem as much as you can. For example, if your goal is to **speed up app start**, then say that. Be as specific as you can. If you've discovered that `Tab2="Chat"` page takes a long time to load, then say that. These improvements to your question make it possible for people to give useful suggestions.

Comment: Yes your right i should be clear in stating my problem. Yes as u said my goal is to speed up my application because my pages in the tabs are heavy and have many bindings and controls inside a collection view. So My application is sending me warning that it is doing heavy load on main thread and skipping 100+ frames. What i am thinking of is loading the xaml part for each tab alone whenever the tab is clicked.

Comment: Explicitly loading the xaml as needed does give you complete control. Just be aware that in my experience, it is not significantly faster (for first load) than what I show (which is very easy to implement). Another good alternative to know about is  `DataTemplate` and `DataTemplateSelector`. You start with a trivial or empty `DataTemplate`; this should be as fast (and easier to code) than manually loading XAML. **BOTTOM LINE:** - XAML **loading** is very fast. Merely deferring that loading is insignificant. Its not until XF does **measure and layout** that it becomes slow.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, what takes most of the time isn't loading the XAML, its a combination of **"measure and layout"**, then **"loading data"** (e.g. the items of a list).

**This example shows how to defer "measure and layout".** It is as simple as setting `IsVisible="False"` on any XAML you want to defer. Then when it is needed, set `IsVisible="True"`. I show the simplest case, where there is no data binding.

**Deferring data loading depends on your data.** The simplest technique is to start all lists (`ListView`, `CollectionView`) with ZERO ELEMENTS. When the data is needed, add the elements. I do not show that below. See [How to load data when a tab is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53993902/199364).

NOTE: **ON Android**, `InitializeComponent` can be sped up further if you have **Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise**. In your `MyProjectName.Android` project, in Project Properties / Android Options (for Configuration `"Release"`) / Code Generation and Runtime, check **"AOT Compilation"**. and "Enable Startup Tracing". You may want to also check "Use LLVM Optimiziing Compiler". These options may increase app bundle size. **Test load time on an actual device** - emulator may give misleading results as to what combination loads fastest. (These options might give very slow load on an Android emulator.)

(Unfortunately, my experience is that Xamarin Forms Android initial app load is still noticeably slower than loading a Xamarin (Native) Android app (I think this is time loading the Xamarin Forms library itself). I recommend creating a native Activity to load immediately, to have a page to show while XF loads. That's a different topic.)

TabbedPage1.xaml:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPage1.Views"
            x:Class="TabbedPage1.TabbedPage1">
    <local:StartPage Title="Start" />
    <local:SlowPage Title="Slow Load" />
</TabbedPage>
```

TabbedPage1.xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TabbedPage1
{
    public partial class TabbedPage1 : TabbedPage
    {
        public TabbedPage1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

SlowPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TabbedPage1.Views.SlowPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="MyContents" IsVisible="False">
            <Label Text="This text should appear after a 3 second delay."
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

SlowPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TabbedPage1.Views
{
    public partial class SlowPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SlowPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            if (!MyContents.IsVisible) {
                // Simulate a page that is slow to layout or load.
                await Task.Delay(3000);
                
                MyContents.IsVisible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

StartPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TabbedPage1.Views.StartPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome!" FontSize="32"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

StartPage.xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TabbedPage1.Views
{
    public partial class StartPage : ContentPage
    {
        public StartPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```